# How to mock 'request' with proxyquire

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, proxyquire

I have a file `foo.js`

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports.getRequest = function (url, headers) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(
            {
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                timeout: 30000,
                headers: headers,
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
                resolve({response, body});
            }
        );
    });
};
```

I want to write a test case for it. but I am not able to write.
can someone help?
I tried something like this.

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire')
    , assert = require('assert')
    , pathStub = {};

describe('Test', () => {

    it('1', () => {
        var foo = proxyquire('./foo', {'request': pathStub});

        pathStub.request = function (file, option) {
            console.log("Request Stub");
            option(null, "a", "b");
        };

        let b = foo.getRequest('file.txt');
        assert.strictEqual(foo.getRequest('file.txt'), 'EXTERMINATE, EXTERMINATE THE FILE.TXT');
    });
});
```

> Error - (node:15344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: request is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You didn't stub `request` function correctly.

E.g.

`foo.js`:

```js
var request = require('request');

module.exports.getRequest = function (url, headers) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(
      {
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        timeout: 30000,
        headers: headers,
      },
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
        resolve({ response, body });
      },
    );
  });
};
```

`foo.test.js`:

```js
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire'),
  assert = require('assert');

describe('Test', () => {
  it('1', async () => {
    const requestStub = function (option, callback) {
      console.log('Request Stub');
      callback(null, 'a', 'b');
    };
    var foo = proxyquire('./foo', { request: requestStub });

    var actual = await foo.getRequest('file.txt');
    assert.deepStrictEqual(actual, { response: 'a', body: 'b' });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  Test
Request Stub
    ✓ 1 (1378ms)


  1 passing (1s)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   85.71 |       50 |     100 |   85.71 |                   
 foo.js   |   85.71 |       50 |     100 |   85.71 | 14                
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```